How to filter to have the longest duration case in an edge
How should a filter be created to show only the case that has the longest duration in an edge between two activities?
In this screenshot I have the green edge which has a maximum duration of 9.14a (years).
I want to filter to find out which specific case it is because it must be an error.
[1
In the desktop application I suppose I should create a filter with an expression, a formula. But I am not clear on how it should be created.
[2
Any ideas?
Thank you!
